# Java: How to insert CLOB into oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, insert, clob

I need to write an XML file content into oracle database where the column is of CLOB datatype.
How will I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**OUTDATED** See Lukas Eder's answer below.

<s>With about 100 lines of code ;-) [Here is an example](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/jdbc/LOBS/CLOBFileExample.java).</s>

The main point: Unlike with other JDBC drivers, the one from Oracle doesn't support using `Reader` and `InputStream` as parameters of an `INSERT`. Instead, you must `SELECT` the `CLOB` column `FOR UPDATE` and then **write into the `ResultSet`**

I suggest that you move this code into a helper method/class. Otherwise, it will pollute the rest of your code.

Comment: Link is unreachable, it requires user and password

Comment: @lanthe Can you please accept Lukas Eders (much superious) answer so I can delete mine?

Answer (score 30):

The easiest way is to simply use the

```
stmt.setString(position, xml);
```

methods (for "small" strings which can be easily kept in Java memory), or

```
try {
  java.sql.Clob clob = 
    oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(
      connection, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

  clob.setString(1, xml);
  stmt.setClob(position, clob);
  stmt.execute();
}

// Important!
finally {
  clob.free();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I didn't try that recently. I'll update my response with an alternative

Comment: what is the use of oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION here?

Comment: @V-spring: An Oracle `CLOB` is a "connected" object with lifecycle that is independent of queries making actual references to it. As far as I know, you can read / write to the actual LOB even after the `INSERT` / `UPDATE` was executed. I'd have to look up details to be sure about this, though...

Comment: @LukasEder What do you consider a "rather small string"?

Comment: Notice `clob.free()` cause compile error due to `Unhandled exception type SQLException`

Comment: @user7294900: I'm obviously assuming you're catching that somewhere or rethrowing it. It's irrelevant to my example.

Comment: I'm using Java, Spring Boot 2.0 and this didn't work for me. I got " com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection". This worked -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791662/inserting-clob-with-namedparameterjdbctemplate

Comment: @DS. I don't think that's really related. You should be able to call `Connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class)`, though.

Comment: this is decrepated

Answer (score 5):

This code worked for me. I use ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.jar.

```
java.sql.Connection con;
javax.xml.bind.Marshaller marshaller;

Clob xmlClob = con.createClob();
try {
  try (Writer xmlClobWriter = xmlClob.setCharacterStream(1)) {
    m.marshal(jaxbObject, xmlClobWriter);
  } // xmlClobWriter.close();
  try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (xml) values(?)")) {
    stmt.setClob(1, xmlClob);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
  }
} finally {
  xmlClob.free();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**passing the xml content as string.**

```
table1 

ID   int
XML  CLOB



import oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement;
/*
Your Code
*/
 void insert(int id, String xml){
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO table1(ID,XML) VALUES ("
                + id
                + "', ? )";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ((OraclePreparedStatement) ps).setStringForClob(1, xml);
        ps.execute();
        result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for [setStringForClob](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html#setStringForClob_int__java_lang_String_)

Answer (score 3):

Converting clob to string:

```
Clob clob=rs.getClob(2);      
String str=(String)clob.getSubString(1,(int)clob.length());      
System.out.println("Clob Data is : "+str);
```

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you need to make the connection result set

> ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE

```
Connection con=null;
//initialize connection variable to connect to your database...
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
String query="Select MYCLOB from TABLE_NAME for update";
con.setAutoCommit(false);
ResultSet resultset=stmt.executeQuery(query);


if(resultset.next()){
oracle.sql.CLOB    clobnew = ((OracleResultSet) rss).getCLOB("MYCLOB");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clobnew.getCharacterOutputStream() );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( new File("filename.xml") ) );
String  lineIn = null;
while( ( lineIn = br.readLine() ) != null )
      pw.println( lineIn );
      pw.close();
      br.close();
}

con.setAutoCommit(true);
con.commit();
}
```

**Note:** its important that you add the phrase for update at the end of the query that is written to select the row...

Follow the above code to insert the XML file

Answer (score 2):

You can very well do it with below code, i am giving you just the code to insert xml hope u are done with rest of other things..

```
import oracle.xdb.XMLType;

//now inside the class......
// this will be to convert xml into string

File file = new File(your file path);
FileReader fileR = new FileReader(file);
fileR.read(data);
String str = new String(data);

// now to enter it into db

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(serverName, userId, password);

XMLType objXml = XMLType.createXML(conn, str);

// inside the query statement put this code

objPreparedstatmnt.setObject(your value index, objXml);
```

I have done like this and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. Changed one of my table column from varchar2 to CLOB.
I didn't needed to change any java code. I kept it as setString(..) only so no need to change set method as setClob() etch if you are using following versions ATLEAST of Oracle and jdbc driver.

I tried in In Oracle 11g and driver ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try this , there is no need to set its a CLOB

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        try{    

                    System.out.println("Opening db");

                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
                    if(con==null)
                     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.9.200.103:1521: orcl","sas","sas");  
                    if(stmt==null)
                    stmt=con.createStatement();  


                    int res=9;

                    String usersSql = "{call Esme_Insertsmscdata(?,?,?,?,?)}";
                    CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(usersSql);
            // THIS THE CLOB DATA  
            stmt.setString(1,"SS¶5268771¶00058711¶04192018¶SS¶5268771¶00058712¶04192018¶SS¶5268772¶00058713¶04192018¶SS¶5268772¶00058714¶04192018¶SS¶5268773¶00058715¶04192018¶SS¶5268773¶00058716¶04192018¶SS¶5268774¶00058717¶04192018¶SS¶5268774¶00058718¶04192018¶SS¶5268775¶00058719¶04192018¶SS¶5268775¶00058720¶04192018¶");     
                    stmt.setString(2, "bcvbcvb");
                    stmt.setString(3, String.valueOf("4522"));
                    stmt.setString(4, "42.25.632.25");
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(5,OracleTypes.NUMBER);    
                    stmt.execute();
                    res=stmt.getInt(5);
                    stmt.close();

                    System.out.println(res);




                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    { 

                         try 
                         {
                            con.close();
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {


                        }
                    }  
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [LobBasicSample](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/BasicSamples/LobBasicSample.java) for an example to use CLOB, BLOB, NLOB datatypes.