# Java Sql Exception

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to retrieve thexml from oracle db and then trying to insert the same xml into the Oracle Database different table.
The select via clob is working fine but its throwing an error while updation.

```
java.sql.Clob myClob = null;
connect = DriverManager.getConnection(str2, str3, str4);
String sql = "select xml from table1 where id='3|32'";
stmt = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    myClob = rs.getClob("XML"); // This part is working fine.


    //Updation


    connect1 = DriverManager.getConnection(str22, str33, str44);
    String query1 = "update documentsout set xml = ?   " +
        "where  id = ? ";
    stmt1 = connect1.prepareStatement(query1);
    stmt1.setString(1, myClob); // Inserting the same CLOB
    stmt1.setString(2, id);
    stmt1.executeUpdate();      // ERROR HERE
```

The error is

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kglgtbo1], [0x700000482AA4608], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Can you please help?

Comment: what version of oracle are you using?

Comment: @Gourav were you able to figure this out? I'm suffering the same problem (albeit for an insert). `.setString()` & `.setClob()` - neither working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should contact your DBA and/or Oracle support representative. According to the documentation on this ORA-00600 error, this is actually an internal problem with Oracle itself.

Source: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
stmt.setClob(position, clob);
```

instead of

```
 stmt1.setString(1, myClob);
```

Comment: I did try with set clob also

Comment: stmt1.setClob(1, myClob); but same result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549450/java-how-to-insert-clob-into-oracle-database , see this may be it help you

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the setClob method

```
  // get clob
  java.sql.Clob clob = (java.sql.Clob) rs.getObject(1);

  // set clob
  String query = "insert into clob_table(id, clob_column) values(?, ?)";
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  pstmt.setString(1, newID);
  pstmt.setClob(2, clob);
```

Comment: Rakesh....as I stated in my last comment...i did try setClob but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This may have limitations, but it worked for my situation. Below, `srcValue` is the value read from the source (src), which was a clob field, and `stmt` is the prepared statement i'm using (in my case, an insert). The target (tgt) is also a clob field.

```
        Clob srcClob = (Clob)srcValue;
        Clob tgtClob = stmt.getConnection().createClob();
        tgtClob.setString(1, srcClob.getSubString(1, (int)srcClob.length()));
        stmt.setClob(icol, tgtClob);
```

I believe clobs are tied to connections/sessions in some way, which requires the workaround.  If there's a better way I'm all ears.