# Passing XML as a CLOB to Oracle gives me "ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value" error

Tags: java, xml, spring, oracle, clob

I am building a web service, which takes an input XML in the payload and stores it in the database.

In the DAO layer, I am creating a clob object with the XML String like:

```
CLOB clob = CLOB.createTemporary(conn,false,CLOB.MODE_READWRITE);
            clob.putString(1,inputXml);
```

I pass this clob object to Stored Procedure:

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter("i_xml", OracleTypes.CLOB));
```

and in the executable method :

```
params.put("i_xml",clob);       
Map<?, ?> result = execute(params);
```

So, when I call this web service, I can see that the XML is being sent to the Oracle DB properly, but I get an error from Database saying :

```
System Error occured while Creating ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value
```

Kindly let me know how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549450/java-how-to-insert-clob-into-oracle-database#5549493) could help you.

Comment: You should also be aware of LOB read consistency and make sure that you avoid commits or rollbacks inside the procedure.

Comment: The third parameter of  `CLOB.createTemporary()` should be either `CLOB.DURATION_CALL` or `CLOB.DURATION_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

The prepared statement should be of type OracleCallableStatement, then follow the sample code as below

```
        stmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call MSG(" + repeatQmarks(7) + ")}");
        stmt.setBigDecimal("P_W_EVENT_LOG_KEY", wEventLogKey); //1      P_W_EVENT_LOG_KEY   IN     NUMBER,
        stmt.setString("P_DOMAIN", domain); //2      P_DOMAIN            IN     VARCHAR2,
        stmt.setString("P_EXCPT_CD", sqlExCd); //3      P_EXCPT_CD          IN     VARCHAR2,
        stmt.setString("P_EXCPT_MSG", sqlExMsg); //4      P_EXCPT_MSG         IN     VARCHAR2,
        stmt.setStringForClob("P_PAYLOAD_IN", "My TEST CLOB 1"); //5      P_PAYLOAD_IN        IN     CLOB DEFAULT NULL,
        stmt.setStringForClob("P_PAYLOAD_OUT", "My TEST CLOB 2"); //6      P_PAYLOAD_OUT       IN     CLOB DEFAULT NULL,
        stmt.registerOutParameter("P_RET_CD", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC); //7      P_RET_CD               OUT NUMBER);
```

Notice how the 5 and 6th params are actually Strings, for the method

> setStringForClob