# ORA-01461 when inserting to a CLOB type from java String

Tags: java, spring, oracle, ibatis

I mapped java String type to CLOB type in ibatis sql config  file and encountering ORA error when i'm inserting a record with this config. This seem to work file when the String's length is 4000 characters or less. To test out long string, i'm creating a random string with 5000 characters in fields (`DATA_CODE` and `SCHEMA_CODE`).

My sql file looks like:

```
<parameterMap class="map" id="map">
<parameter property="QUERY_HASH" javaType="java.math.BigDecimal" jdbcType="NUMBER" />
<parameter property="LOCATION" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR2" />
<parameter property="HOST_NAME" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR2" />
<parameter property="SERVER_PORT" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR2" />
<parameter property="DATA_CODE" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="CLOB" />
<parameter property="SCHEMA_CODE" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="CLOB" />
<parameter property="CREATED" javaType="java.util.Date" jdbcType="DATE" />
</parameterMap> 
<insert id="INSERT__QUERY_CACHE" parameterClass="map">
    <![CDATA[
    INSERT INTO "QUERY_CACHE" (query_hash, location, host_name, server_port, data_code, schema_code, created)
    SELECT #QUERY_HASH#, #LOCATION#, #HOST_NAME#, #SERVER_PORT#, #DATA_CODE#, #SCHEMA_CODE#, #CREATED# FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
    SAVRO_CONN_QUERY_CACHE WHERE query_hash = #QUERY_HASH# and location=#LOCATION# and host_name = #HOST_NAME# and server_port = #SERVER_PORT#)
    ]]>
</insert>
```

and my java code is:

```
Map<String, Object> iterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
iterMap.put("QUERY_HASH", key);
iterMap.put("LOCATION", cacheEntry.className);
iterMap.put("HOST_NAME", hostName);
iterMap.put("SERVER_PORT", serverPort);
////// junk string - START
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("5000 chars string");
builder.append(RandomStringUtils.random(5000));
iterMap.put("DATA_CODE", builder.toString());
iterMap.put("SCHEMA_CODE", builder.toString());
//// junk string - END
iterMap.put("CREATED", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
insert(QRY__INSERT, iterMap);
```

Exception trace is:

```
        org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [1461];
    --- The error occurred in com/mycomp/sql_config.xml.
    --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
    --- Check the INSERT__QUERY_CACHE-InlineParameterMap.
    --- Check the statement (update failed).
    --- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
    ; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
    --- The error occurred in com/mycomp/sql_config.xml.
    --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
    --- Check the INSERT__QUERY_CACHE-InlineParameterMap.
    --- Check the statement (update failed).
    --- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.insert(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:367)
    at com.mycomp.mypackage.MyCache.saveCache(MyCache.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
    --- The error occurred in com/mycomp/sql_config.xml.
    --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
    --- Check the INSERT__QUERY_CACHE-InlineParameterMap.
    --- Check the statement (update failed).
    --- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeUpdate(MappedStatement.java:107)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.insert(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:393)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.insert(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:82)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$8.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:369)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:203)
    ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3685)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeUpdate(SqlExecutor.java:80)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.sqlExecuteUpdate(MappedStatement.java:216)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeUpdate(MappedStatement.java:94)
    ... 19 more
```

We're using ibatis 2.3.4 and Spring 3.3
I searched in other posts addressing similar issues but i couldn't find a clue from them. Any clues please..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no easy way to insert large values in Oracle from Java as the JDBC driver has no native support for Reader and Inputstream. This is explained in another topic on SO:
[Java: How to insert CLOB into oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549450/java-how-to-insert-clob-into-oracle-database)

Comment: I was using ibatis. I figured out a way to do it with ibatis itself. refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing `insert into .. select if not exists`. My requirement was to insert data only if it doesn't exist in table. It worked after

- Splitting this into two separate queries - one for select, one for
  insert.
- Since, i'm sending a map parameter anyways, I removed paramMap xml.
- appended CLOB to query args in the xml

  ```
  <insert id="INSERT__QUERY_CACHE"
  parameterClass="Map">
  <![CDATA[
  INSERT INTO "QUERY_CACHE" (query_hash, location, host_name, server_port, data_code, schema_code, created)
  values (#QUERY_HASH#, #LOCATION#, #HOST_NAME#, #SERVER_PORT#, #DATA_CODE:CLOB#, #SCHEMA_CODE:CLOB#, sysdate)
  ]]>
  </insert>

  <select id="SELECT__FROM_CACHE" resultClass="int">
  <![CDATA[
  SELECT count(0) as CNT FROM QUERY_CACHE WHERE query_hash = #QUERY_HASH# and location=#LOCATION# and host_name = #HOST_NAME# and server_port = #SERVER_PORT#
  ]]>
  </select>
  ```

In Java,

```
Map<String, Object> selectMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
selectMap.put("QUERY_HASH", key);
selectMap.put("LOCATION", cacheEntry.className);
selectMap.put("HOST_NAME", hostName);
selectMap.put("SERVER_PORT", serverPort);

Integer count = (Integer) queryForObject(QRY__SELECT_FROM_CACHE, selectMap);
if(count == 0) {
    Map<String, Object> iterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    iterMap.put("QUERY_HASH", key);
    iterMap.put("LOCATION", cacheEntry.className);
    iterMap.put("HOST_NAME", hostName);
    iterMap.put("SERVER_PORT", serverPort);
    iterMap.put("DATA_CODE", cacheEntry.dataCode);
    iterMap.put("SCHEMA_CODE", cacheEntry.schemaCode);
    insert(QRY__INSERT, iterMap);
}
```