# Java: How to insert JSON object to CLOB into oracle database

Tags: java, json, oracle, prepared-statement, clob

I have a `org.json.simple.JSONObject` and I want to insert it into a clob type column in Oracle Database using PreparedStatement. How can I do that?

When I do `preparedStatement.setObject(1, json_obj);` I get the error : Can''t infer the SQL type in setObject for org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: Why not convert the `JSONObject` or a JSON `String` and insert the text?

Comment: The column type in database cannot be changed from clob to anyother type. When I try 
    `preparedStatement.setString(1, json_obj.toString()); ` I get SQL error: 1036 ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: Well, you should be using `toJSONString` instead of `toString` so you get the actual JSON structure

Comment: Also, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549450/java-how-to-insert-clob-into-oracle-database)

Comment: `toJSONString` gives same SQL error: 1036 ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number. As suggested in above link tried `oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);` which gives org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection. I believe there should be an easier way.

Comment: See the linked example - you may not be able use `setObject`

Comment: I am using `setString` instead of `setObject`

Comment: [Read the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549450/java-how-to-insert-clob-into-oracle-database)

Comment: it suggests creating a `OracleResultSet`, using `inputBufferedReader ` and `putChars` method along with lot of other code. I believe there should be a much simpler way to solve my problem.

Comment: Several of the answers create a `CLOB`, you might look at those

Comment: Tried `OraclePreparedStatement` but it gives org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement error. `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller` cannot be used in my case. If you have any other suggestions apart from that link kindly provide those.

Comment: Do a goggle on "Oracle JDBC CLOB"

Comment: I have already googled before posting a question here. Kindly provide a useful link or solution that would be helpful. And to reiterate I want to insert a JSONObject in a database column of type clob.

Comment: *"And to reiterate I want to insert a JSONObject in a database column of type clob"* - Just so were clear on that point, `JSONObject` is an Object, CLOB is "character large object" - you can't insert the Object into the column, you can only insert the result of `toJSONString`, which is text

Comment: `preparedStatement.setString(1, json_object.toJSONString())` gives SQL error: 1036 ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but you're trying to insert the `String` into the CLOB column, so you can't use `setString`, you have to use `setClob`, but using the text, not the object - Maybe something like [How to Insert Clob or Blob via JDBC](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/04/27/lets-review-how-to-insert-clob-or-blob-via-jdbc/) which seems to create it's own wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I put the json as a String and created this method, it worked for me:

```
public long  insertClob(String  id, String json ) {
    KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE tableWithClobColumn SET clobColumn=? WHERE id=?",
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        Reader reader = new StringReader(json);
        ps.setClob(1, reader);
        ps.setString(2, "1911030604");

        return ps;
    }
}, holder);
return Long.parseLong("0");
}
```